# Wrong Aggregation when nulls (Mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

So I have data which has null or no document for certain data points.
Here is some set of commands demonstrating data

```
db.perfR.find({platform:"mac", "filename" : "f1.json"},{filename:1, platform:1, int_secs:1, version:1, _id:0})

{ "filename" : "f1.json", "platform" : "mac", "version" : "1.4.14", "int_secs" : 15 }
```

Indicates only one entry for "Mac"

```
db.perfR.find({platform:"win", "filename" : "f1.json"},{filename:1, platform:1, int_secs:1, version:1, _id:0}).count()

0
```

Indicates no entry for Win

Here is the aggregation command

```
db.perfR.aggregate([ {$sort:{version: -1 }},{ $group:{ _id: {platform:"win", "filename" : "f1.json", version:"$version"}, avgSecs: {$avg:"$int_secs"} } }])
```

And output

```
{ "_id" : { "platform" : "win", "filename" : "f1.json", "version" : "1.4.13" }, "avgSecs" : 759 }
{ "_id" : { "platform" : "win", "filename" : "f1.json", "version" : "1.4.14" }, "avgSecs" : 415.46153846153845 }
{ "_id" : { "platform" : "win", "filename" : "f1.json", "version" : "3.0.0_dev" }, "avgSecs" : 563.8333333333334 }
```

I am quiet confused where does Mongodb get all that data from and how to restrict it to look for values that are present.

Note: There are other entries for other versions, which I have not shown here for brevity.

Any pointers to improve the aggregation command would be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing string literals in your group _id specification:

```
_id: {platform:"win", "filename" : "f1.json", version:"$version"}
```

`"win"` and `"f1.json"` are just string literals. Only one field from documents is used in _id - it's `"$version"`. So you got three groups for three different version values which you have in your documents.

Correct _id definition would be

```
_id: {platform:"$platform", filename : "$filename", version:"$version"}
```

That will group documents by three fields.

NOTE: if you want to filter collection by some field, you should use $match stage for that.